# How does one post images to a profile with facebook connect?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I have facebook connect setup for an app but I am not sure how to allow the user to share images from within the app to the facebook connect profile?

Is this possible, if so how does one do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how to post a status already? If yes, then you just need to include another parameter called "attachment" in the dictionary parameter.

[Steam API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish) and [Stream Attachment API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/attachments)

Comment: Thanks, but for the source argument, type': 'image', 
'src': 'http://icanhascheezburger.files.wordpress.com/2009/03/funny-pictures-kitten-finished-his-milk-and-wants-a-cookie.jpg', can it be a png file from within the app?

Comment: I think yes, if you want to test, put your image link inside the link box of facebook website. If facebook can get it, then you can use it:)